# Pandas applying condition across columns for a large dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a dataframe `df` which has data as follows:

```
  Date          Var         Avg     Run_1   Run_2   Run_3   
  2019-01-01    V1          3.16    3.41    3.84    3.17    
  2019-01-02    V2          66024   0       1       287     
  2019-01-03    V1          3.16    3.41    3.84    3.17    
  2019-01-04    V2          66024   0       1       287
```

The columns Run_1, Run_2 extend all the way to Run_5000. Date is the index column

I am trying to create another dataframe `df2` from above which has the following:

```
  Date         V1_M           K=Avg_V1*v1_M   Val1    Val2    Val3
  2019-01-01   1.00            3.16        0.25      0       0   
  2019-01-02   1.01            3.19        0.22      0       0   
  2019-01-03   1.02            3.22        0.19      0       0   
  2019-01-04   1.03            3.25        0.16      0       0
```

The formula to get Val1, Val2, Val3, ..., Val500 is:

```
=MAX(Run_1_V1 - K, 0)*IF(Run_1_V2 > 0, 0, 1)
```

`Avg_V1` refers to `V1` variable from Avg column in `df`

`Run_1_V1` refers to `V1` from `Run_1` column in `df`

My current approach gets stuck after this, due to 500 columns of `Run_1, Run_2, ..Run_500`, as I am not sure how to apply the formula above to all of 500 columns without writing an explicit for loop:

```
v1 = df[df['Variable'] == 'V1']
v2 = df[df['Variable'] == 'V2']
```

Edit:
Formula for Val500:

```
=MAX(Run_500_V1 - K, 0)*IF(Run_500_V2 > 0, 0, 1)
```

`Run_1_V2` refers to `V2` from `Run_1` column in `df`

Comment: What is the formula for `Val500`?

Comment: What is Run_1_V2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the numpy way. First, extract your *runs* matrix:

```py
runs = df[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Run_')].values
```

Then, zero out all the values you dont want with a binary mask

```py
var_col = df.VAR.str[1:].astype(int).values
mask = np.zeros((var_col.size, var_col.max()))
mask[np.arange(len(var_col)), var_col-1] = 1
```

And apply the mask and the `K` factor:

```py
values = runs * mask * new_df.K.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Then you can wrap the result with the `np.ndarray` constructor of a `pd.DataFrame`